# UnitTesting method returning IObservable<T> from WP assembly

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, system.reactive

I have a WP7 assembly with a `Foo` class defined in it.

```
public class Foo
{
    IObservable<int> Bar() { ... }
}
```

I need to unit test that method using Visual Studio 2012 MSTest.

I have a .net Framework 4.5-based unit test project created in Visual Studio 2012 which references my WP7 assembly.

The most simple test for it is

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    var bars = foo.Bar();
}
```

The problem is I get an error message and am not able to compile that test project:

```
error CS0012: The type 'System.IObservable`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly 
that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Observable, 
Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e'.
1>C:\Work\App2\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs(41,35,41,42): error CS0029: Cannot 
implicitly convert type 'System.IObservable`1<int>' to 'System.IObservable<int>'
```

Unfortunately IObservable in WP is defined in System.Observable.dll while in .net Framework 4 it is defined in mscorlib.dll. I am not able to use the same IObservable defining assembly for my WP and UnitTest projects. My usual App.config `<bindingRedirect>` trick does not work when interface is defined in different assemblies.

How can UnitTests for WP projects with IObservables in VS 2012 be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using something like what is done in [this article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html). I use this to target multiple environments and it works well. You would just need to have a project for your WP tests with links to all your test files.

Comment: Well, finally I had to do it that way.

Comment: The bad side is I test linked files only, not real production assembly. 
Sooner or later test project (with linked files) and real project might become different, We have 100+ projects in our solution so it might be a pain to keep file links in test projects.

Comment: Your test project should be a separate assembly that just references either the wp8 version or the wp7 version. You should not have extra links.